# Add DataSet Bar Chart - Chart.JS

Tags: dataset, bar-chart, chart.js

I´m tryng to make a bar chart in chart.js (using chart.js 2.2.2)

I´m in trouble trying to put new datasets in a chart

How can i put a new Dataset "Vendas" with data: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]

```
var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Compras",
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            }
        ]
    };
var ctx = $("#barOrgaoAno").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: "bar",
            data: data,
});
```

I tried two examples i got in the internet but i can´t get neither to work

Exemple 1

```
barChartDemo.addData([dData()], "dD " + index);
```

Exemple2

[JSFLiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvak6rkx/)

```
var myNewDataset = {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(187,205,151,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(187,205,151,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(187,205,151,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(187,205,151,1)",
        data: [48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90, 28]
    }

    var bars = []
    myNewDataset.data.forEach(function (value, i) {
        bars.push(new myBarChart.BarClass({
            value: value,
            label: myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[i].label,
            x: myBarChart.scale.calculateBarX(myBarChart.datasets.length + 1, myBarChart.datasets.length, i),
            y: myBarChart.scale.endPoint,
            width: myBarChart.scale.calculateBarWidth(myBarChart.datasets.length + 1),
            base: myBarChart.scale.endPoint,
            strokeColor: myNewDataset.strokeColor,
            fillColor: myNewDataset.fillColor
        }))
    })

    myBarChart.datasets.push({
        bars: bars
    })

    myBarChart.update();
```

Comment: Do you want to include the Vendas set at the beginning or add it afterwards?

Comment: Will be 2 bars in label January, one for "Compras" and one for "Vendas" and so on for every month , don´t matter if it add before or after

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you store your chart data in a variable (called `data` in your code), you can do it with a simple function on a button :

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    // You create the new dataset `Vendas` with new data and color to differentiate
    var newDataset = {
        label: "Vendas",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 255, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(99, 255, 132, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
    }

    // You add the newly created dataset to the list of `data`
    data.datasets.push(newDataset);

    // You update the chart to take into account the new dataset
    myBarChart.update();
});
```

---

You can see the full code [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mL5n3o2/) and here is its result after a click :

[image]

Comment: Note:  the `data` variable here can be replaced with `myBarChart.data` for the same effect. (just mentioning because at first glance I didn't realize what `data` was, and had to read the OP to find out)

Answer (score 0):

based on tektiv answer only, it didn't work for me.
I constructed the newDataSet just like he suggested, but I had a problem while pushing the Data.
to fix this, i had to do:

```
data.config.data.datasets.push(newDataSet);
```

instead of:

```
data.datasets.push(newDataSet);
```